# Filter for slug, title not working in Django rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to make a dynamic search but cant seem to filter queryset by slug. I have tried just about everything and went through stackoverflow questions and nothing seems to solve it. I have tried changing the keyword to "id" and "category" and I get a result but not on slug.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyaik.png)  is the error/no queryset I received.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi3FV.png) is the filter I made for authors which seems to work.
Here is the code, Please inform if I need to provide more code to understand the problem as this is my first question here. Thanks!

**blog_api/views.py**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from blog.models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer
from rest_framework.permissions import SAFE_METHODS, IsAuthenticated, IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, BasePermission, IsAdminUser, DjangoModelPermissions
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import filters
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.response import Response


class PostUserWritePermission(BasePermission):
    message = 'Editing posts is restricted to the author only.'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.author == request.user

     
class PostList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    # queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user)


class PostDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView, PostUserWritePermission):
    # permission_classes = [PostUserWritePermission]
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        item = self.kwargs["pk"]
        print(item)
        return Post.objects.filter(slug=item)
```

**blog_api/urls.py**

```
from .views import PostList, PostDetail
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

app_name = 'blog_api'

# router = DefaultRouter()
# router.register('', PostList, basename='post')
# urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('posts/<str:pk>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='detail_create'),
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='list_create'),
]
```

**blog/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Post(models.Model):

    class PostObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status="published")

    options = (
        ("draft", "Draft"),
        ("published", "Published"),
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    excerpt = models.TextField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date="published")
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_post")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default="published")

    objects = models.Manager()
    post_objects = PostObjects()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-published"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: You can't use `slug` as a lookup_field because it is not unique. It is unique only for a certain date. If you want to use it, make it unique, then set lookup_field in your view to `slug`.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I am still a learner, if you dont mind can you please elaborate... thanks again

Comment: When you want to get details for an object you have to make sure that the field that you're filtering by is unique because if not, you cand get more results and django won't know which one is the right one. In your case 'slug' is no unique. There can be multiple posts in your table with the same slug,

Comment: Alright, I seem to get what you said, So should I change the slug field in models to unique=True and add lookup_field in post detail view or is there any other suggestions I should try to fix it.

Comment: That should do it.

Comment: That did it! Thanks man you are great.

Answer (score 0):

in your PostDetail class in blog_api/views.py file, instead of overriding get_queryset method, override get_object method, like this

```
    def get_object(self, queryset=None, **kwargs):

        item = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_object_or_404(Post.objects.filter(slug=item))
```